# How do I copy the content of a cell in org-mode table?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Is there a command to copy the content of a cell in a single keystroke?

When I have cursor at [x] (see below), I have to do: `M-a` (goes to the beginning of the cell), `C-<SPC>`, `M-e` (goes to the end of the cell), and `M-w`. There should be an easier way!

```
| Title 1            | Title 2        |
|--------------------+----------------|
| This is [x] a cell | This is a cell |
|                    |                |
```

Comment: If you are trying to duplicate the contents of a cell down a column, there is an easier way to do that: `org-table-copy-down` (bound to `S-RET`). For general copying through the kill ring, a keyboard macro would probably be the simplest method: do `C-h i g(emacs)Keyboard macros` to find out more.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest this bind to `C-c y' (or whatever key you want)

```
  (bind-key (kbd "C-c y")
            (lambda()(interactive)
              (when (org-at-table-p)
                (kill-new
                 (string-trim
                  (substring-no-properties(org-table-get-field))))
                (message "copied cell: @%d$%d"
                         (org-table-current-line)
                         (org-table-current-column) )))
            org-mode-map)
```

Comment: Not bad ! So we get the value of the cell at point with `org-table-get-field`. I don't understand why this function, called with `M-:`, also returns the org table formatting, and how this formatting disappears when `kill-new` is called, but... it's simple, and it works well.

Comment: There's one small issue, though, which is that it puts many unnecessary spaces in the clipboard, when the column is larger than the copied field.

Comment: Spaces are not in the clipboard. check it when inserting within plain text. If you insert it in a cell, just type C-c C-c to get rid of unwanted spaces.

Comment: Well, I did check, and they are there alright. If I copy the cell "Title 1" in my example above, and paste the result outside the table, what I get is `Title 1            ` - that is, with 12 trailing spaces at the end. Is that not what you observe? (For reference, my org-version is 9.4.4)

Comment: My apologize, you are right. I corected the answer to trim blanks characters.

Comment: does this solve the problem? If so, accept the answer, it will be my pleasure.

Comment: Thks gigiair ! I have been testing your solution for a few days, and I did upvote it, but two things are still missing for me to accept it: 1) the command should give the output "Copied Cell", exactly like `M-w` gives the output "Copied line", because it's a little stressing to have no output at all when you execute a command; 2) the answer should begin by suggesting the simpler way of using `S-RET` and `S`+ directional arrows suggested by NickD (see my answer below), because that is what solved 90 % of my use cases. If you add these two points, I'll delete my answer and accept yours.

Comment: @kotchwane For (1) simply add a `(message "Copied cell")` in the lambda, after the `(kill-new...)` form, something like `... (when (org-at-table-p) (kill-new ...) (message ...))`

Comment: I made the desired modification. I just added the display in the message of the address of the copied cell.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that `org-mark-element` doesn't do what I would call "the right thing" here. This short function seems to copy a cell when your cursor is in a cell, and otherwise the element around the cursor.

```
  (defun copy-element ()
   (interactive)
   (let* ((oec (org-element-context))
      (begin (org-element-property :begin oec))
      (end (org-element-property :end oec)))
     (kill-new
      (cond
       ;; for a cell the end includes the trailing | so we don't count that.
       ((eq 'table-cell (car oec))
    (buffer-substring begin (1- end)))
       (t
    (buffer-substring begin end))))))
```

Comment: If you are in a table cell, `org-element-at-point` returns `table-row`. There is a fine distinction (which I have not understood) between `elements` and `objects`: a `table-row` is an `element` but a `table-cell` is an `object`. So you'd need a clone of `org-mark-element` (`org-mark-object`?) that uses `org-element-context` as you note, instead of `org-element-at-point`. But as you also note, there are some annoying features, like the inclusion of the trailing `|`: a `table-cell` should not include its delimiters IMO.

Answer (score 0):

NickD provides in his comment a method that solves 90 % of the use cases - those where we need to copy a cell to another cell of the table.

Just do `S-RET` to copy the cell to the cell below, and then move the copied cell to its desired location by pressing Shift plus any of the arrow key (`S-<up>`, `S-<down>`, `S-<left>` and `S-<right>`).